# How to delete bulk certs from org

Tags: apex, community, metadata-api, workbench

I have production data in my sandbox i don't want the production certs in my sandbox i would like delete certs in a bulk using apex or workbench or any other tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can query them via the Tooling API as [`Certificate`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_certificate.htm).

To actually delete them will require the Metadata API - [`Certificate`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_certificate.htm). This could be via the [`deleteMetadata()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deleteMetadata.htm) API call or a [push of a destructiveChanges.xml file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy_deleting_files.htm). You may find it easier to use the SFDX CLI `force:source:delete` command.

Before you can delete them from an org you will likely need to remove any other metadata that references those certificates.